# Translating LSTM model from Pytorch to Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, pytorch, lstm

I have an existing model in Pytorch and I am trying to translate it to TensorFlow. It is a neural network with two hidden LSTM layers and a multiple output because my goal is to do multi-class classification. My input is a time serie where each value represents a given class and I want to predict the next one. My time series has been converted to a vector by using a window of size 10.
The thing that is bugging me is that in pytorch my model gives awesome predictions but in tensorflow my accuracy drops and my loss function gets stuck.

I am pretty sure that the data I input into model is in the shape it needs so i am only going to post the model itself for now.

**Pytorch code**

```
class Model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, num_layers, num_keys):
        super(Model, self).__init__()
        self.hidden_size = hidden_size
        self.num_layers = num_layers
        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(input_size, hidden_size, num_layers, batch_first=True)
        self.fc = nn.Linear(hidden_size, num_keys)

    def forward(self, input):
        h0 = torch.zeros(self.num_layers, input.size(0), self.hidden_size).to(device)
        c0 = torch.zeros(self.num_layers, input.size(0), self.hidden_size).to(device)
        out, _ = self.lstm(input, (h0, c0))
        out = self.fc(out[:, -1, :])
        return out
```

**TF code**

```
modeltf = keras.models.Sequential([
  keras.layers.LSTM(hidden_size, return_sequences=True,
                         batch_input_shape=(batch_size, 10, 1)),
  keras.layers.LSTM(hidden_size, return_sequences=False),
  keras.layers.Dense(num_classes),
])

modeltf.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(),
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['sparse_categorical_accuracy'])
```

If anyone can see the difference or has any recommendation I'll be grateful :)